# Query times out in SP, but runs fine in query analyzer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

I seem to be facing a strange issue in SQL 2008.

I have a query which runs fine and fast from query analyser, but times out if run through a stored procedure! The SP just starts with this query and has no other code before this query

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM TBL1 (nolock)
INNER JOIN TBL2 (nolock) 
ON tbl1.col=LEFT(tbl2.col1,LEN(tbl2.col1)-2) AND tbl1.col2=RIGHT(tbl2.col1,2)
AND tbl1.col4=2233
AND tbl1.date1 BETWEEN tbl2.date1 and isnull(tbl2.date2,getdate())
```

Please note that tbl1 is actually a view, where the col and col2 are coming via a self join. Also as per business requirement, tbl2.col1 needs to have concatenated value. If required to solve this issue, I can modify my view though.

Comment: This is usually a problem with missing indexes or stale statistics. Incidentally, stop using `NOLOCK`, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side issue, please note that if you can make some assumptions about string lengths, your join expression can be simplified (and possibly get better performance because one side is now using equality):

```
SELECT tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2
FROM
   TBL1
   INNER JOIN TBL2

      ON tbl1.col + tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1
      AND tbl1.col4=2233
      AND tbl1.date1 BETWEEN tbl2.date1 AND Coalesce(tbl2.date2, GetDate())
```

Also, if you're looking for the best performance, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE TBL2 ADD LeftPart AS (LEFT(col1, LEN(col1)-2));
ALTER TABLE TBL2 ADD RightPart AS (RIGHT(tbl2.col1,2));
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TBL2_Parts ON TBL2 (LeftPart, RightPart);
```

Now you can just join like so:

```
SELECT tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2
FROM
   TBL1
   INNER JOIN TBL2
      ON tbl1.col = tbl2.LeftPart
      AND tbl1.col2 = tbl2.RightPart
      AND tbl1.col4=2233
      AND tbl1.date1 BETWEEN tbl2.date1 AND Coalesce(tbl2.date2, GetDate())
```

**Even better**, change your database design to actually store the TBL2.col1 data in two columns. You're violating first normal form by putting two distinct pieces of data in one column, and now, as you're discovering, you're paying for it throughout your application in terms of performance, development & maintenance time, query complexity, and so on.

You could even reverse my scheme so that the LeftPart and RightPart columns are real, and you create a new calculated column that has the Col1 name, with an index to materialize the values and make them searchable. Finally, if absolutely required, you could rename the table, create a view on the table using the old name, and then put an INSTEAD-OF triggers on the view to intercept data operations against the table and translate them into the correct schema.

**Update**

By the way, if you have any influence on table design you may want to consider using an "open ended date" value of '99991231' or some such for tbl2.date2 rather than NULLs. That Coalesce can kill performance, sometimes forcing a scan when a seek would have been possible.

Comment: Your observations and suggestions are very valid and just. Ideally, I tried using a syntax such as ON tbl1.col + tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1 and by adding the index on left and right side as you suggested but was not able to, because tbl2 is actually a VIEW, and the VIEW has self join on a table to generate the left and right columns. I guess a view with a self join cannot have index :(

Comment: As I cannot have index on tbl2,  ON tbl1.col + tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col1 becuase MUCH slower than even my current syntax. Lastly, I cannot store left and right part originally in separate columns as that is a specific business requirement in my case. So I am very lost here :/

Comment: On the other hand, getting idea from your suggestion, I added two computed columns to my TBL2 to add Left and Right computed columns. And the query seems to be working now in SP!! Trying it completely now. Will postback if it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. You still have open to you the option to store the parts in 2 columns, as long as there is a calculated column to provide the concatenated value. And like I said, if updates and inserts are required, you can rename the table and create a view that replaces it, with INSTEAD OF triggers to handle DML.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar situations in the past that were caused by [parameter sniffing](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/17/sql-parameter-sniffing-and-what-to-do-about-it/).  You might try the method discussed in  the article above and see if it makes a difference.

What happens is that when you run the stored procedure for the first time SQL Server caches it's execution plan and uses it going forward.  If you run the stored proc with parameters that make this execution plan not optimal you can see the behavior you are describing.

You can also use the query hint `recompile` to make sure that it uses a new execution plan every time it executes.  To do this you would add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query:

```
SELECT id, name 
from tableName
WHERE id between @min and @max
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

[This link](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/-using-the-recompile-query-hint-to-solve-parameter-sniffing-problems.aspx) goes over several solutions for the parameter sniffing problem.

Comment: Adding option (recompiled) didn't help :( Going through the articles you mentioned

Comment: `option(recompile)` really helps with date manipulations in-place